# Vuejs 303 redirect

Tags: vuejs2, http-status-code-303

In my Vuejs application on calling API to make a payment and I get 303 as  status code and In the header, I can see Location:

> http://local.xyz.in:1024/payment-success

In the browser's network console, I can see log for

> http://local.xyz.in:1024/payment-success

but the page doesn't redirect to payment-success page and show following error on the console

> Failed to load http://local.xyz.in:1024/payment-success:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do API use header for allow origin ?? *

Answer (score 0):

You are running into CORS issues. There are several ways to fix/workaround this.

- Turn off CORS. For example [how to turn off cors in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)
- Use a [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for your browser